# How to change UIImage when the app is about to enter background - swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I want the image to change when the app enter or is about to enter background.

File name **AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    ViewController().changeImg();        
}
```

File name **ViewController.swift**

```
func changeImg(){
    backgroundImg.image =  UIImage(named: "blue") as UIImage;
}
```

But I gen an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
ViewController().changeImg()
```

you are instantiating a new, empty ViewController, which does not have the `changeImg` method. You need a reference to your custom viewController.

If that viewController is your rootViewController you can find it in your appDelegate via

```
// create a property in appDelegate for your viewController
var viewController: ViewController?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as UINavigationController
    viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ViewController
}
```

Then you can call

```
viewController?.changeImg()
```

Comment: I see and how I can do that?

Comment: let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewControlle as UINavigationController
    
    
    self.viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ViewController

Comment: The above code assumes that your viewController is the rootViewController of your navigation controller. Other solutions are possible. Just store a reference to your viewController where you create it.

Comment: Its a single view app, but only this var viewController: ViewController? dosent work

Comment: But I can println() in the refresh func, using my code but I cant change the background img

Comment: What is the name of your custom viewController class? I assumed you have named it `ViewController`. Replace that with your current class name

Comment: Yes it is ViewController

Comment: Then you should have a file `ViewController.swift`

Comment: Yes that is the name of the file, but yet I cant change the background image from AppDelegate.swift